# Split Data into two table on Crystal Report + VB NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am developing an application that display Data from database to CReport. I am using VB NET and Crystal Reports to do this. The report comes out fine when only print one table same as data table from query database. e.g

```
Group Name  Amount
A     Test1 10
A     Test2 11
A     Test3 10
B     Test4 11
B     Test5 12
```

actually data quite a long up to three pages of report and more than 3 field,9 field exactly,and now i wanna display data report split on two table horizontaly **based on group field**,the left table group A and the other on the right table group B, on the same page of report. e.g

```
Group Name Amount       Group  Name   Amount
A     Test1 10          B      Test4  11
A     Test2 11          B      Test5   12
A     Test3 11
```

Can someone please tell me how to accomplish this ???

Comment: You mean write the code for you?

Comment: no, i mean..its possible in crystall report ?and how to do that?

Comment: You know what crystal report does? Why do you VB in there?

Comment: im using vb to call query stored procedure in database...actually my problem in crystal report to split one table from database in two table on crystall report on the same page

Answer (score 0):

you just need to copy the same data field to the other side of the report. Left click the data field, select suppress and start entering the formula:

```
YourFieldName = 'A'
```

for the right horizontal 
and 
    YourFieldName = 'B' 
for the left horizontal.
Then the section should be formatted according to what you needed, by displaying A only at the left side and B only at the right side

Put those field in the detail section first before applying the formula.

Comment: or u can use subreport

Comment: i have tried using formula as you write..and the B group not display on left table, otherwise B group print on right table..but B group printed after the A group fisnished printed...so the B group not display on the first page, and the right table in first page is blank..so how to print B group in top as A group(equal)..thnx befrore yuan ling.

Comment: @andry Now, I remember, the cross tab. Try refer this link: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/153417-possible-to-group-data-horizontally